# How to make template helper reactive?

Tags: meteor

I am using a JQueryUI slider in one of my forms to select a value within a range. I want to display this value next to the slider, which means I need to make the getter method for the slider method reactive

```
Template.payments.rendered = function () {
  $( "#requestAmount" ).slider({
     min: 10,
     max: 50,
     step: 1,
   });
};


Template.payments.helpers({

  requestAmount: function() {
    var value = $( "#requestAmount" ).slider( "option", "value" );
    return value;
  },
  ....
```

HTML

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">

 <div id="requestAmount"></div>
    <div class="requestAmount">
      {{requestAmount}}
    </div>
 ...
```

One is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your helper to be reactive, it has to return a reactive data source such as a `ReactiveVar` for example (you need to `meteor add reactive-var` first).

We need to assign a reactive var to the slider template like this :

```
Template.payments.created=function(){
  this.sliderValue=new ReactiveVar(0);
};
```

Then we can return the value of this reactive data source in our helper

```
Template.payments.helpers({
  sliderValue:function(){
    Template.instance().sliderValue.get();
  }
});
```

Finally we have to set the reactive var value whenever our slider is changed.

```
Template.payments.events({
  "slidechange #requestAmount":function(event,template){
    var sliderValue=template.$("#requestAmount").slider("option","value");
    template.sliderValue.set(sliderValue);
  }
});
```

You may want to wrap all this in a reusable Meteor package and even publish it as a package.

HTML

```
<template name="UISlider">
  <div id="{{id}}" class="ui-slider">
    <div class="ui-slider-widget"></div>
    <div class="ui-slider-value">{{value}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.UISlider.created=function(){
  this.value=new ReactiveVar(0);
};

Template.UISlider.helpers({
  value:function(){
    return Template.instance().value.get();
  }
});

Template.UISlider.events({
  "slidechange":function(event,template){
    var value=template.$(".ui-slider-widget").slider("option","value");
    template.value.set(value);
  }
});
```

This reusable Meteor component could be used like this :

HTML

```
<template name="payments">
  {{> UISlider id="requestAmount"}}
  <p>{{sliderValue}}</p>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.payments.helpers({
  sliderValue:function(){
    var $slider=Template.instance().$("#requestAmount");
    var sliderInstance=Blaze.getView($slider.get(0));
    return sliderInstance.value.get();
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure one can catch jQuery UI-events in `Template.templateName.events`?

Comment: You can catch any HTML5 DOM events using Meteor event maps, and it's usually better to do so because it plays nicely with Blaze, in particular when templates get destroyed, events will automatically get unlistened.